# Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Console - default login and password?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I've just installed an Oracle 11g Standard Edition Database. It ran successfully and everything, however when going to Oracle Enterprise Manager Im not really sure what my "username" would be.

I entered a password during the installer, and I tried SYS and my password connecting as "Normal" and "SYSDBA". However, I'm not really sure what my username is meant to be. Is it just that I haven't set up a username/password for this yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the Oracle 11.2 installation document describing the [administrator user accounts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba.htm#ADMIN11042) after installation.  Once logged in, you would change passwords with the syntax

```
alter user system identified by mynewpassword;
```

Note the `SYS` and `SYSTEM` accounts are assigned the `DBA` role. The `DBA` role does not have a password, the accounts do. The `DBA` role is created with every installation. You could grant the `DBA` role to another user if needed.

Comment: Please update the provided link. It's broken.

Answer (score 6):

The best account to login to the Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Control (EMDC) is the **SYSMAN** user account; with it, you are logging in as the proper EMDC super user. Use NORMAL mode, not `AS SYSDBA`.

Alternatively, you can use SYSTEM (specifying mode `AS SYSDBA`).

This is per 11.1 manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/rev_precon_db.htm#autoId1

The same manual describes how to, being in EMDC, convert another "normal" database user (the one you use in sqlplus) into an EMDC-capable user. Or, from within EMDC, you can create a new user: a database user that is both EMDC-capable and sqlplus-capable from the beginning.

As SYSMAN wouldn't have a password by default after install, you need to assign it. Just login to sqlplus with SYS AS SYSDBA and issue:

```
alter user sysman identified by "MyPass!@#$" account unlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a browser, and access the Enterprise Manager Cloud Control Console

```
https://<oms_host_name>:<console_port>/em
```

Enter the user name `sysman`, and the password you provided for this user account at the time of installation.